# Comparação de elementos de um vetor com "strcmp()"

Tags: c, array, string, comparação

Na seguinte função quero comparar os elementos de um *array* de 1000, porém não consigo achar uma forma de compará-las com êxito, mesmo usando `strcmp()`.

```
void verifica_conta(int *ptr) {
    int i; //Posição
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
       if(strcmp(*ptr, *(ptr+i)) == 0) {
          printf("\tConta já existente\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Não faz sentido comparar dois inteiros com `strcmp()` já que esta função compara *strings*.

Seria algo assim:

```
void verifica_conta(int *ptr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) if (ptr[0] == ptr[i]) printf("\tConta já existente\n");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/StrCmp.c).

Mas é até provável que tenha um erro de lógica também.